# How to find if number is round/integer or float/double

Tags: c

Im working with big numbers , 241 233 ,662581978748022 i wanna find if 
 662581978748022/241/233 is round or float number ... all of them are long long int , if i try to do

double var=662581978748022/241/233 = it still outputs round number e.g xxx.0000 even if it isnt round number, and bcs of it when i compare
 double var=662581978748022/241/23 == long long int var2=662581978748022/241/23  its still true when it shouldnt how can i find if its round or float number other way?

Comment: Look into the modulo operator `%`. Also integer division always results in an integer. Convert one or more of the numbers into floats or doubles to get a floating point result.

Comment: Show your output statement, better still, a MCVE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `662581978748022/241/233` are all `int`-type values.  Thus the result will be an `int`-type value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `x = integer-number (operator) integer-number` the right part is computed as an integer. Whatever the `x` type.

Example:

```
double x;
x = 3/2;
```

Now `x` is "1.000…". Because 3 is integer, 2 is integer, so the operation is performed as integer. It is then converted to `double` for the `=`.

If you want you operation to be performed as float/double you must cast at least one of the right member:

```
double x;
x = (double)3/2;
```

Now `x` is "1.5".

So your `double var=662581978748022/241/233` (it is the same if numbers are integer variables) is computed as an integer value.
As said by @Kevin use modulo (%) to get remaining stuff or use floating values.